# Good book about replicating portfolios

Tags: options, risk-neutral-measure, replication, coherent-risk-measure

I want to know if anybody can suggest me a good textbook which explains in detail and in an understandable way how to create replicating portfolios of financial instruments like options "cash or nothing", "asset or nothing". Moreover I want to know if there's any good book which explains the change of measure between objective probability and risk neutral probability... Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm attending a course about this stuff and the professor provides lecture notes badly written that don't tell the whole story...

Answer (score 2):

As always I recommend reading [Rennie and Baxter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521552893) for an introduction to option pricing that's not too technical and gives intuition about how it all works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've browsed the book a bit and found a lot of information, not to mention countless worked examples. It would be extremely helpful if somebody could alzo recommend a book - or maybe even on line lecture notes or exercises that expain well how to replicate portfolios of cash or nothing or asset or nothing options... I've heard that for CoN there's a paper of Breeden-Litzenberger (1978) but maybe it's too advanced and I need to have a grasp of the things on a more basic level...